# update record fails giving duplicate entry error

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `placements` (
  ......
  ......,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pl_id`),
  KEY `cur3` (`currency`),
  KEY `pl2` (`date_arranged`),
  KEY `pl3` (`start_date`,`end_date`),
  KEY `pla_peo_id` (`peo_id`),
  KEY `pla_placed_with` (`placed_with`),
  KEY `pla_reh2` (`remind_agent`,`status`,`end_date`),
  KEY `reh_temp2` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `pl_id` (`pl_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pla_comp_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`placed_with`) REFERENCES `companies` (`pid`),
  CONSTRAINT `pla_con_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`peo_id`) REFERENCES `contractors` (`pid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have above table structure. I want to update my table for pl_id = 320636 and set end_date with new value.

```
update placements set end_date = '2016-03-09 00:00:00' where pl_id = '320636'
```

giving Duplicate entry '320636-2016-02-15 00:00:00' for key 'PRIMARY' error.

I tried to remove primary key but no luck.Please help me in this ?

Comment: The error is in a key that joins an id and a date. The fact that no such key exists in your schema, and the date in the error differs from the one in the query in your update, suggests that the information you've given here is incomplete. What happens if you use a different date? What happens if you remove the constraints?

Comment: Is your primary key an auto_increment ? If it is, what are it's properties? Is it a `tinyint, int, signed or unsigned` in nature ? Your solution lies there I'd think

Comment: The date in error is date set to start_date for that pl_id.If I use date before the start date i.e 2009-03-09 00:00:00 in this case it works fine.

Comment: Is there another table with a primary key on id and start date, which references this one?

Comment: My primary key is not auto incremented .I Have old code that get max +1 pl_id and inserts new record.primary key `pl_id` int(8) NOT NULL,

Comment: there is no another table with a primary key on id and start date, which references this one?